# Can I Move A File on my Server using JSP?

Tags: file, jsp, move

I usually work with PHP but need to setup this JSP with a server that I am interacting with. Here is the code I am trying:

```
<%
String filename = request.getParameter("file");
filename = "C:\Tomcat 5.5\webapps\myapp\\" + filename;
out.print(filename);

ActiveXObject theObject = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
File theFile = new theObject.GetFile(filename);

theFile.Move("C:\Tomcat 5.5\webapps\myapp\processed\\");

%>
```

The goal is to send in a request to `http://www.thewebsite.com/myfile.jsp?file=x.txt` and the JSP file should take `x.txt` and move it to the `processed` directory.

When I call this JSP file I get an error that says `ActiveXObject cannot be resolved to a type` ... so, I guess that I can't do it this way.

Is it possible to move a file using JSP?

Comment: JSP means **Java** Server Pages. You should read the **Java** api reference, instead of blindly trying to use objects that obviously could only exist on Windows. Java is a multi-platform language. http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/. Also, read this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
ActiveXObject cannot be resolved to a type
```

usually means that we need to import the class where ActiveXObject resides. In JSP use import directive to import the package you need.

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
```

Hope this helps!